# Finding the degree of the splitting field

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Find the degree of the splitting field of $f(x)=x^3-3x-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. I know that this polynomial is irreducible by using Eisenstein's criteria(by letting first $x=y+1$), and for every cubic polynomial $f∈\mathbb{Q}[x]$, the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a radical extension. But how can I start my work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The degree is 3. Since $f$ is irreducible, $L=Q[x]/(f)$ is a separable field of degree $3$ since the characteristic of $Q$ is zero. $Gal(L:Q)$ has order 3 and is generated by $h$. Let $u$ be a root of $f$ in $L$ we can take $u$ to be the class of $x$ in $Q[x]/(f)$, $h(u)\neq u$ since $u$ is not in $Q$.  $h(u),h^2(u)$ are also roots of $f$ and remark that $u,h(u), h^2(u)$ are distinct (example, $h(u)=h^2(u)$ implies $h(h(u))=h^3(u)=u, h^2(u)=u, h(h^2(u))=h(u)=u$ contradiction). This implies that $L$ is a splitting field and $f=(X-u)(X-h(u))(X-h^2(u))$.

Comment: How do you know that the Galois group has order $3$?  We can't even really speak of the Galois group since we don't know the extension is Galois, just the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(L|\mathbb{Q})$.  Anyway, your reasoning seems to apply equally well to $x^3 - 2$ which has trivial automorphism group.

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_s%C3%A9parable#Morphisme_dans_la_cl.C3.B4ture_alg.C3.A9brique

Comment: What is this link supposed to tell me?  $x^3 - 2$ generates a separable degree $3$ extension, too.

Comment: This link tell you that  $L$ is a separable extension of $F$, if and only if  the cardinal of the Galois group $Gal(L:F)$ is the degree $[L:F]$

Comment: I don't see where it says that in the link.  To be Galois, an extension must be separable **and [normal](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_normale)**, i.e., all roots of the polynomial must also be contained in the field.  I don't see where you've shown that, and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ is an example of an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is separable but not normal: it doesn't contain the two other roots $\zeta \sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{2}$ where $\zeta$ is a primitive $3^\text{rd}$ root of $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Our cubic is irreducible over the rationals by the Rational Roots Theorem.

Let $x=2t$. Our equation becomes $4t^3-3t=\frac{1}{2}$. Let $t=\cos\theta$. The roots $t$ are the $\cos(\theta)$, where $\cos(3\theta)=\frac{1}{2}$.

The roots $t$ are therefore the cosines of $20^\circ$, $100^\circ$, and $140^\circ$. Note that $\cos(140^\circ)=-\cos(40^\circ)=-(2\cos^2(20^\circ)-1)$. So the roots of our equation are all contained in $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(20^\circ))$, and therefore the splitting field has degree $3$ over the rationals.

Comment: If $\alpha $ is a root there is another defined by $2\beta=\alpha+\sqrt{(\alpha)^2-\frac{4} {\alpha}}$. This makes me to be wrong about the degree. Thank you. Your answer is fine.

Comment: I gave this answer for fun, because of its connection to a famous problem. Degrees were deliberate, to give it a retro look.

Comment: trisection of the angle, by chance?

Comment: Yes, one works with $4t^3-3t=\frac{1}{2}$ to show that the $20^\circ$ angle is not compass and straightedge constructible.

Comment: Absolutely, the only constructible magnitudes are these expressed algebraically by formulas leading to extensions of $\mathbb Q$ of degree  $2^n$ (and degree $3$ is not of this kind). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the $\DeclareMathOperator{\Gal}{Gal} \Gal(f)$ as a permutation group on the roots of $f$, since $f$ is irreducible, then $\Gal(f)$ must be a transitive subgroup of $S_3$. There are only two such transitive subgroups: $A_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $S_3$ itself.

Recall that the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial $h$ of degree $n$ is a subgroup of $A_n$ iff the discriminant of $h$ is a square. (See Dummit and Foote, $\S14.6$, Proposition $34$ or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558382/galois-group-and-discriminant-delta-f2), for example.) Since the discriminant of $f$ is
$$
-4 (-3)^3 - 27 (-1)^2 = -27(-4 + 1) = 81 = 9^2 \, ,
$$
then $\Gal(f) \cong A_3 \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.